# Are all values in columns TRUE ignoring NA

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

**I am working in R**

Edit: hoping for a dplyr suggestion

**sample data:**

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA), 
                 col2 = c(FALSE,  TRUE, FALSE, NA), 
                 col3 = c(NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE))

print(df)
```

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE | NA |
| TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| NA | FALSE | NA |
| NA | NA | TRUE |

**Desired outcome**

I would like a way of assessing whether col1 --> col3 are all TRUE, ignoring the NAs.

| col1 | col2 | col3 | assessment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | FALSE | NA | FALSE |
| TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| NA | FALSE | NA | FALSE |
| NA | NA | TRUE | TRUE |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` either using `rowwise`

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(assessment = all(across(everything()), na.rm=T)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  col1  col2  col3  assessment
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>     
1 TRUE  FALSE NA    FALSE     
2 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE      
3 NA    FALSE NA    FALSE     
4 NA    NA    TRUE  TRUE
```

or using `pick`, thanks @r2evans

```
mutate(df, assessment = apply(pick(col1:col3), 1, \(x) all(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
  col1  col2 col3 assessment
1 TRUE FALSE   NA      FALSE
2 TRUE  TRUE TRUE       TRUE
3   NA FALSE   NA      FALSE
4   NA    NA TRUE       TRUE
```

With **base R**, using `all`

```
cbind(df, assessment = apply(df, 1, \(x) all(x, na.rm=T)))
  col1  col2 col3 assessment
1 TRUE FALSE   NA      FALSE
2 TRUE  TRUE TRUE       TRUE
3   NA FALSE   NA      FALSE
4   NA    NA TRUE       TRUE
```

Comment: And the [tag:dplyr] variant: `mutate(df, assessment = apply(pick(col1:col3), 1, \(x) all(x, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: @r2evans Right, haven't seen the tags. Gonna add it! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry both - did not mention that hoping in dplyr - thanks for spotting the tag @r2evans

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` twice to check if the number of TRUE matches the number of complete values by row:

```r
df$assessment <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE) == rowSums(!is.na(df))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it:

```r
Reduce(`&`, replace(df, is.na(df), TRUE))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

### Tidyverse variant

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(assessment = Reduce(`&`, Map(coalesce, ., TRUE)))
```